# Full URL not getting Submitted (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am submitting my form on click of SAVE.

```
$('#btnSave').click(function () {

    $('#frmFurtherRelevantInformation').submit();

});
```

And my URL is
    http://My.local/TP/FurtherRelevantInformation/655/29

And I have four routes in Global.asax

```
#region Further Relevant Information

        routes.MapRoute(
          "FurtherRelevantInformation",  // Route name
          "TP/FurtherRelevantInformation/{SubstanceId}", // URL with parameters
          new { controller = "TP", action = "FurtherRelevantInformation", SubstanceId = UrlParameter.Optional }  // Parameter defaults
          );

        routes.MapRoute(
         "TPFurtherRelevantInformation", // Route name
         "TP/FurtherRelevantInformation/{SubstanceId}/{JobServiceMapId}", // URL with parameters
         new { controller = "TP", action = "FurtherRelevantInformation", SubstanceId = UrlParameter.Optional, JobServiceMapId = UrlParameter.Optional }  // Parameter defaults
         );

        routes.MapRoute(
          "FurtherRelevantInformationHttpPost", // Route name
          "TP/FurtherRelevantInformation/{SubstanceId}", // URL with parameters
          new { controller = "TP", action = "FurtherRelevantInformation", SubstanceId = UrlParameter.Optional },  // Parameter defaults
          new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("POST") }
          );

        routes.MapRoute(
         "TPFurtherRelevantInformationHttpPost",  // Route name
         "TP/FurtherRelevantInformation/{SubstanceId}/{JobServiceMapId}",  // URL with parameters
         new { controller = "TP", action = "FurtherRelevantInformation", SubstanceId = UrlParameter.Optional, JobServiceMapId = UrlParameter.Optional },  // Parameter defaults
         new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("POST") }
         );
        #endregion
```

Since the page may have the 2nd parameter or may be not.
But in case when URL has with 2nd parameter , in POST method of my Controller i am not getting the second parameter, i.e. 29.

I checked the Request URL in Chrome is showing only http://My.local/TP/FurtherRelevantInformation/655.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is all of your URLs will match `TP/FurtherRelevantInforamtion/{id}` before they match `TP/FurtherRelevantInformation/{id}/{id}` so the first route is always hit.

If you want to prioritize the multi-parameter URLs then you need to register them *before* your single parameter route

```
routes.MapRoute(
     "TPFurtherRelevantInformation", // Route name
     "TP/FurtherRelevantInformation/{SubstanceId}/{JobServiceMapId}", // URL with parameters
     new { controller = "TP", action = "FurtherRelevantInformation", SubstanceId = UrlParameter.Optional, JobServiceMapId = UrlParameter.Optional }  // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
      "FurtherRelevantInformation",  // Route name
      "TP/FurtherRelevantInformation/{SubstanceId}", // URL with parameters
      new { controller = "TP", action = "FurtherRelevantInformation", SubstanceId = UrlParameter.Optional }  // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "TPFurtherRelevantInformationHttpPost",  // Route name
    "TP/FurtherRelevantInformation/{SubstanceId}/{JobServiceMapId}",  // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "TP", action = "FurtherRelevantInformation", SubstanceId = UrlParameter.Optional, JobServiceMapId = UrlParameter.Optional },  // Parameter defaults
    new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("POST") }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "FurtherRelevantInformationHttpPost", // Route name
    "TP/FurtherRelevantInformation/{SubstanceId}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "TP", action = "FurtherRelevantInformation", SubstanceId = UrlParameter.Optional },  // Parameter defaults
    new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("POST") }
);
```